# How can I redraw my datatable with new data after ajax success?

Tags: json, ajax, draw

I have an Ajax call, that on success outputs me json data:

```
success : function (data) {
alert(data);
```

The output of `data` is

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 570,
  "recordsFiltered": 570,
  "data": [
    [
      "id":536,
      "name":"Accountant",
      "city":"Tokyo",
      "timestamp":"11.02.2020"
    ],
    [
      "id":537,
      "name":"Friend",
      "city":"Havanna",
      "timestamp":"11.02.2020"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have a datatable already on my page. And I want now, after the ajax success, reload the table with the new data.

> NOTE: The json has only 2 entries, but it is important, that the
>   records total are displayed as 570

This is my approach:

```
success : function (data) {

  var table =  $('.table').DataTable();

  table.clear();
  table.destroy();
  table.rows.add(JSON.parse(data));
  table.draw();
```

The result is an empty datatable without data.

This is the function that creates data:

```
public function getJson($fileName,$length) {

    $file = 'files/'.$fileName.'.json';

    $input = file_get_contents($file);
    $array = json_decode($input);

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if($key == "data"){
        $new = array_slice($value, 0, $length);
      }
    }

    $array->data = $new;
    $data = json_encode($array);
    return new Response($data);
```

And this is the initial datatable:

```
  var table = $('.table').DataTable({
     "serverSide": true,
     "ajax": '{{ path('json', { fileName: output.fileName }) }}',
```

....

I cannot post the whole table because it is really long code...

Comment: you dont need to reinit the datatable, just call table.draw() or table.ajax.reload()

Comment: @AhmedSunny But how do I then add the new json data?

Comment: @AhmedSunny Can you give an example with `data`?

Comment: how are ou getting the json? by ajax? can you share your initial datatable and complete function of getting json

Comment: @AhmedSunny I updated my question for you

Comment: in the success function try this way `table.ajax.reload();`  or try  `table.clear().draw();   table.rows.add(NewData);`

Comment: or try this table.clear().rows.add(newData).draw();

Comment: do you mean add `table.ajax.reload();` to the others or replace the code with this

Comment: remove everything in success part and then try, replace everything you did for redraw in success, also var table  = datatable .. ..

Comment: I tested `table.ajax.reload();` and the old data stays like it is, no change

Comment: I tested `table.clear().draw(); table.rows.add(data);` and I get the error `DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter 'timestamp' for row 0`

Comment: This is probably a good sign that at least something is happening right?

Comment: check your new data, this warning is related to data, may be its null or wrong, check network tab/XHR/ you ajax call

Comment: @AhmedSunny I cannot figure it out why this is has a warning